# How do I calculate a Rectangle around a Geographic Point?

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude, cllocation

CLLocationManager will hand off to my delegate a new CLLocation whenever location has changed. The coordinates of that location are expressed as a CLLocationCoordinate2D object, which simply contains a latitude and a longitude. I'd like to take this location and determine the latitude and longitude 1000m south and 1000 west and the latitude and longitude 1000m north and 1000m east. This way I end up with one coordinate southwest of the location and one northeast of the location.

I have no clue how to do this, and my GoogleFoo seems quite poor tonight. What information I have found has offered up impenetrable mathematics. Anybody help a brotha hacker out? I'm fine to use an iOS API if there is one, but an equation that just operates on `double` values for the lat and long would be even better. It doesn't have to be accurate within centimeters, though within meters would be nice. Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
NSArray *rect = CalculateRectangleFromLocation(
    clLocationCoordinate2D,
    1000.0
);
```

And then *rect would have four values: the lat and long of the southwest corner and the lat and long of the northeast corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code to get the top/right/bottom/left coordinates of the bounding rectangle.

**LatLon.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

extern double radians(double degrees);
extern double degrees(double radians);

extern CLLocationCoordinate2D LatLonDestPoint(CLLocationCoordinate2D origin, double brearing, CLLocationDistance distance);
```

**LatLon.m**

```
const CLLocationDegrees kLatLonEarthRadius = 6371.0;

double radians(double degrees) {
    return degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
}

double degrees(double radians) {
    return radians * 180.0 / M_PI;
}

CLLocationCoordinate2D LatLonDestPoint(CLLocationCoordinate2D origin, double bearing, CLLocationDistance distance) {
    double brng = radians(bearing);
    double lat1 = radians(origin.latitude);
    double lon1 = radians(origin.longitude);

    CLLocationDegrees lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(distance / kLatLonEarthRadius) + 
                                  cos(lat1) * sin(distance / kLatLonEarthRadius) * cos(brng));
    CLLocationDegrees lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(brng) * sinf(distance / kLatLonEarthRadius) * cos(lat1),
                                                      cosf(distance / kLatLonEarthRadius) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2));
    lon2 = fmod(lon2 + M_PI, 2.0 * M_PI) - M_PI;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    if (! (isnan(lat2) || isnan(lon2))) {
        coordinate.latitude = degrees(lat2);
        coordinate.longitude = degrees(lon2);
    }

    return coordinate;
}
```

**Usage**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = ...;
double distance = ...;

CLLocationCoordinate2D right = LatLonDestPoint(location, 90.0, distance);
CLLocationDegrees rectRight = right.longitude;

CLLocationCoordinate2D top = LatLonDestPoint(location, 0.0, distance);
CLLocationDegrees rectTop = top.latitude;

CLLocationCoordinate2D left = LatLonDestPoint(location, 270.0, distance);
CLLocationDegrees rectLeft = left.longitude;

CLLocationCoordinate2D bottom = LatLonDestPoint(location, 180.0, distance);
CLLocationDegrees rectBottom = bottom.latitude;
```

**Swift**

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    fileprivate func radians(degrees: Double) -> Double { return degrees * .pi / 180.0 }
    fileprivate func degrees(radians: Double) -> Double { return radians * 180.0 / .pi }

    func coordinate(bearing: Double, distanceInMeter distance: CLLocationDistance) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        let kLatLonEarthRadius: CLLocationDegrees = 6371.0
        let brng: Double = radians(degrees: bearing)
        let lat1: Double = radians(degrees: self.latitude)
        let lon1: Double = radians(degrees: self.longitude)

        let lat2: CLLocationDegrees = asin(
            sin(lat1) * cos(distance / kLatLonEarthRadius) +
            cos(lat1) * sin(distance / kLatLonEarthRadius) * cos(brng)
        )

        var lon2: CLLocationDegrees = lon1 + atan2(
            sin(brng) * sin(distance / kLatLonEarthRadius) * cos(lat1),
            cos(distance / kLatLonEarthRadius) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2)
        )
        lon2 = fmod(lon2 + .pi, 2.0 * .pi) - .pi

        var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        if !lat2.isNaN && !lon2.isNaN {
            coordinate.latitude = degrees(radians: lat2)
            coordinate.longitude = degrees(radians: lon2)
        }
        return coordinate
    }

    func rect(distanceInMeter meter: CLLocationDistance) -> (north: Double, west: Double, south: Double, east: Double) {
        let north = coordinate(bearing: 0, distanceInMeter: meter).latitude
        let south = coordinate(bearing: 180, distanceInMeter: meter).latitude
        let east = coordinate(bearing: 90, distanceInMeter: meter).longitude
        let west = coordinate(bearing: 270, distanceInMeter: meter).longitude

        return (north: north, west: west, south: south, east: east)
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks almost perfect Jayant, thanks! One question: when you say top/right/bottom/left, do you mean north/east/south/west? Probably a stupid question, but which are the values for lat and long in the southwest corner and which are the lat and long for the northeast corner?

Comment: Left/Bottom = West/South = rectLeft/rectBottom. Right/Top = East/North = rectRight/rectTop.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by using the PROJ4 library to convert latitude and longitude to a projection in meters that's useful for my region (UTM works well if you don't have more information, I'm in Northern California so surveyors in my region all work in EPSG:2226), adding the appropriate offset in meters to that, and then using PROJ4 to convert back.

Later edit: The answer given by Jayant below is fine, depending on how accurate your meters rectangle needs to be. The earth isn't a sphere, it isn't even an oblate spheroid, so the projection in which add your distance to your latitude and longitude may matter. Even using PROJ4 those meters are at sea level. Geography is harder than you'd think.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect it will be fine, since I don't anticipate needing a rectangle more than 100km on a side.